# Mysql save article on the 31 of December at 14:25 but data function showing the date in 2019

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.6

Mysql save the article like that: 2018-12-31 14:25:37. But on the website the date is like that: 31 December 2019, 2:25 pm. Here is my code.

`date("d F o, g:i a", strtotime($article->created_at))`

The data show show right year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`o` is [for *ISO-8601 week-numbering year*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

> This has the same value as Y, except that if the ISO week number (W)
>   belongs to the previous or next year, that year is used instead.
>   (added in PHP 5.1.0)

You should use `Y`:

```
date("d F Y, g:i a", strtotime("2018-12-31 14:25:37"))
// 31 December 2018, 2:25 pm
```